# Python TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got float

Tags: python, python-2.7

friends, I'm new to python and trying to plot three curves with each other, but I have some problems which I can't figure out:

I try to solve trajectory of a ball with different vectors:

1- different x values
2- different velocity values
3- different angle values

```
     import numpy as np
import math as m
import matplotlib.pylab as pl


def ball(x, theta, v0, y0):
    v0= v0/3.6
    g = 9.81
    theta = m.radians(theta)
    return x * m.tan(theta) + y0\
              - 1./(2.0 * v0 ** 2.0 ) * g * x**2.0 / (m.cos(theta)**2)

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)

#part1
theta = 60
y0 = 1.0    
v0= 15.0
y = ball(x, theta, v0, y0)
pl.plot(x, y)


#part2
theta = 60
y0 = 1.0
for v0 in range(10.0, 60.0, 10.0):
  y2 = ball(x, theta, v0, y0)
  pl.plot(x, y)

#part3
y0 = 1.0
for theta in range(0.0, 112.5, 22.5):
   y3 = ball(x, theta, v0, y0)
   pl.plot(x, y)

pl.plot(x, y, "r*")
pl.plot(x, y2, "bo")
pl.plot(x, y3, "y^")
pl.xlabel("X")
pl.ylabel("Y")
pl.legend(["x,y","x,y","x,y"])
pl.show()
```

please help me what is going on ??

Comment: So what's unclear about the error message? You are passing in floating point numbers into the `range()` function. Pass in integers instead.

Comment: my problem was that i should use floating, now i know how i can use it, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `range` function does not accept floating point numbers as arguments, so you *must* use integers. What you can do instead, then, is to just increase each part of the `range` function by a factor of 10, and then decrease it by a factor of 10 within the loop. For example:

```
for i in range(int(0.0*10), int(112.5*10), int(22.5*10)):
    realI = i/10.0
    #now realI is the float you had wanted originally.
```

Comment: No problem! Though you should mark it as the answer then so that future people can find it!

Answer (score 0):

Range(start value, end value, step)

You can't use floating type numbers, use integers.

Answer (score 0):

From Python 2.7 Documentation on [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range):

> This is a versatile function to create lists containing arithmetic
>   progressions. It is most often used in for loops. ***The arguments must
>   be plain integers.*** If the step argument is omitted, it defaults to
>   1. If the start argument is omitted, it defaults to 0. The full form returns a list of plain integers [start, start + step, start + 2 *
>   step, ...]. If step is positive, the last element is the largest start
>   + i * step less than stop; if step is negative, the last element is the smallest start + i * step greater than stop. step must not be zero
>   (or else ValueError is raised).